# How does ¯¯¯¯¯ become ùùùùùùùùù

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have tried: `echo ¯¯¯¯¯` 
but the result becomes

```
ùùùùùùùùù
```

this was not the output expected.
the expected output was ¯¯¯¯¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous solution, which saves the batch script in `Unicode UTF-8 without BOM` and `codepage 65001` seems to have issues with both console and `C` runtime as user @eryksun mentioned.

@eryksun also mentioned in our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152769/discussion-between-stevefest-and-eryksun):

> Like I said, all of the codepages are supersets of ASCII, so what I mean is to limit the rest of the batch script to just ASCII characters, because they can be decoded properly regardless of the console codepage.

---

## Unicode UTF-8

```
chcp 65001
echo ¯¯¯¯¯
chcp [Original Codepage]
```

Explanation by @eryksun:

> CMD decodes line by line, i.e. you can change to codepage 65001 just for the non-ASCII lines and then switch back to the original codepage.
>
> If you don't use an editor such as Notepad++ that can save UTF-8 without a BOM (byte order mark), CMD will see the first line as an error since it doesn't know to ignore a BOM.

Comment: CMD uses the console's legacy codepage for encoding and decoding files (otherwise it uses Unicode). The batch file needs to be saved as UTF-8 *without a BOM*. I recommend only changing the console codepage temporarily to read the string into an environment variable. Save the original codepage, and restore it after the variable is set. Otherwise limit the batch file to 7-bit ASCII characters. Avoid leaving the console in UTF-8 mode because both the console and the C runtime have bugs with using codepage 65001, which affects console applications that use the legacy codepage API.

Comment: Oh okay. Is 7-bit's ASCII cp 65000 or something else? Saving without BOM is of course possible, but would require more "advanced" text editor. Perhaps I should put save to ASCII instead.

Comment: Turns out I did a quick search and the codepage is `20127` instead of `65000`.

Comment: 7-bit ASCII is limited to the first 127 Unicode ordinals. All of Microsoft's legacy (non-Unicode) codepages are supersets of ASCII, as is UTF-8. So whatever the codepage is you know you're safe if you stick to ASCII. You can temporarily switch the console to UTF-8 via `chcp.com 65001`, which works great when decoding a batch script since CMD decodes line by line, i.e. you can change to codepage 65001 just for the non-ASCII lines and then switch back to the original codepage.

Comment: If you don't use an editor such as Notepad++ that can save UTF-8 without a BOM (byte order mark), CMD will see the first line as an error since it doesn't know to ignore a BOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152769/discussion-between-stevefest-and-eryksun).